# trigger initialization function on document.ready to load default information

Tags: javascript, jquery

Almost sure this has not been asked before.
I need to run an initialization function on document.ready as i will be using the same function to refresh the content on user request.
so function to run once on document.ready then be callable during the document lifetime.

I must admit I have no idea where to even begin with this.
ok so let me edit my code will look loke this

```
<div class="drag panel_box" id="drag">
<ul id="drag_list">

</ul>
</div>

<div class="drop panel_box" id="drop">
<ul id="drop_list">

</ul>
</div>

<div class="info panel_box">
  <div id="filters"></div>
  <div id="information"></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#drag_list').append('<li class="draggable">Item 1</li>').draggable();
$('#drag_list').append('<li class="draggable">Item 2</li>').draggable();
$('#drag_list').append('<li class="draggable">Item 3</li>').draggable();
$('#drag_list').append('<li class="draggable">Item 4</li>').draggable();
$('#drag_list').append('<li class="draggable">Item 5</li>').draggable();

});
</script>
```

so basically i want to run the append statement on entry and then on ever call to the reset button

Comment: Then define a function and pass it in: `document.ready(func)`

Comment: "Almost sure this has not been asked before." I'm almost sure you're wrong.

Comment: `$(myfunction)` will do it. >> Almost sure you didn't have used the search function

Comment: when i used the search function it listed a number of posts none of which where what i was looking for. second what i did find only mentioned that statements would be run when it was loaded. passing a function in the ready porion is my standard practice with jquery, all my other functions are loaded within it. ie: $(document).ready(function(){ my functions all go in here so if i pass a different function to the initial what happens to my other functions});

Comment: @TerenceBruwer so please provide concrete sample of what you are looking for. And you shouldn't wrap functions definition inside ready handler

Comment: ok i use an ajax call to repopulate a draggable and droppable interface, when the user selects one of the items in the draggable and drops it I trigger a lookup to go find matching data if no matches are found i give them a button to repopulate the draggable list if they want to. now that repopulate function is what i would like to trigger in my initialization call

Comment: so have you tried: `$(repopulate)` and `$('#buttonid').on('click',repopulate)`, repopulate function should be defined in global scope or at least on same scope. But again, sample code would better help to understand your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting down-voted here. If I understand you're question, you're trying to create a function which loads some content. You want it to load content on the initial page load, and you want to be able to call the same function at a later stage when you want to load new content.

What I don't understand is why you can't do

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   function loadContent(content_request_params){
     return content;
   }

   loadContent('initialize');  //this is run on initialize

   $('#load_content').click(function(){  //this is run later on user action
             loadContent('load-on-click')
           });
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing it working http://jsfiddle.net/2Lq46/

Comment: so on this example loadcontent will only run the once on document.ready?

Comment: Yes, you are calling the function within the document.ready, so it will fire once, then each time you click the `#load_content`, you'll be firing it again.